# Selenium - Unable to Interact with Input textbox

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Using Python Selenium, I am trying to interact with "https://www.screener.in/explore/" page with has a input textbox to search for a Company name. But the code throws an error
"raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable"

Below is the code using Python

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.screener.in/explore/")

button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='u-full-width']")
button.send_keys("TCS")

time.sleep(100)
```

From the HTML page source, the input tag

```
 <input
    aria-label="Search for a company"
    type="search"
    autocomplete="off"
    spellcheck="false"
    placeholder="Search for a company"
    class="u-full-width"
    
    data-company-search="true">
```

My goal is to search for the company in that textbox and page leads to company details page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong element.

Input from your locator is input for mobile view, and it is hidden (as far as your dimensions are corresponding web view). As far as it is hidden, it doesn't have size / location, so it is not interactable.

Instead you can filter inputs by that locator for visibility and use first input that is visible.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

URL = "https://www.screener.in/company/compare/00000085/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(URL)

company_inputs = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type=search]')))
visible_input = [element for element in company_inputs if element.is_displayed()][0]
visible_input.click()
visible_input.send_keys('Boeing')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working as I wanted to be.